# Documents went missing from top left bar in nautilus. user-dirs.dirs updated but no results

Tags: nautilus, bookmarks

A crack of my touch screen laptop and the fiddling of the mouse made a folder disappear from nautilus (TOP) bookmarks : Home,Downloads, Pictures, etc. It probably moved my Documents folder somewhere else, which I fixed.

I went to update `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`, where the `Documents` line was missing, so I added it.

I updated through:

```
xdg-user-dirs-update
xdg-user-dirs-gtk-update
xdg-user-dirs-update --force
```

and rebooted few times but the directory doesn't come back.

Can you help?

My `user-dirs.dirs` file looks like that:

```
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run.
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
#
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set `XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"` and, a few lines below, you set it again as `XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/"`. The last setting effectively overrides the previous.

Just delete the `XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/"` line and you should be fine.

Comment: not working for me. there is no `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` and I also don't recall messing with that kind of stuff either

Comment: @mcExchange Running `xdg-user-dirs-update` should create the file.